# Allocating a buffer of more a page size on stack will corrupt memory?

Tags: windows, stack, memory-management, size

In Windows, stack is implemented as followed: a specified page is followed committed stack pages. It's protection flag is  as guarded. So when thead references an address on the guared page, an memory fault rises which makes memory manager commits  the guarded page to the stack and clean the page's guarded flag, then it reserves a new page as guarded.

when I allocate an buffer which size is more than one page(4KB), however, an expected error haven't happen. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Excellent question (+1).

There's a trick, and few people know about it (besides driver writers).

When you allocate large buffer on the stack - the compiler automatically adds so-called **stack probes**. It's an extra code (implemented in CRT usually), which probes the allocated region, page-by-page, in the needed order.

**EDIT:**

The function is `_chkstk`.

Comment: Documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648426%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ah, so whats why I get linker errors to __chkstk in my no crt app with large stack vars..

Answer (score 3):

The fault doesn't reach your program - it is handled by the operating system. Similar thing happens when your program tries to read memory that happens to be written into the swap file - a trap occurs and the operating system unswaps the page and your program continues.

Comment: Almost correct. This is what happens when you access the stack sequentially and cross the next page boundary. However in the described scenario, when you allocate large variables on the stack, extra trick is needed.