# What is the purpose of the _chkstk() function?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, callstack

I recently used the [`/FAsu` Visual C++ compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx) to output the source + assembly of a particularly long member function definition.  In the assembly output, after the stack frame is set up, there is a single call to a mysterious `_chkstk()` function.

The MSDN page on [`_chkstk()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648426.aspx) does not explain the reason why this function is called.  I have also seen the Stack Overflow question [Allocating a buffer of more a page size on stack will corrupt memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4123609/196844), but I do not understand what the OP and the accepted answer are talking about.

What is the purpose of the `_chkstk()` CRT function?  What does it do?

Comment: My guess (after reading your links) is that the function sets up protection so writes just outside the functions stack will be caught by the CRT, and can be handled like throwing exceptions in C++ or other things.

Comment: Related: [How is Stack memory allocated when using 'push' or 'sub' x86 instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46790666) (also covers Linux, which doesn't need stack probes: it has a different heuristic for whether to grow the stack or treat it as an invalid page fault => segfault).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Windows pages in extra stack for your thread as it is used. At the end of the stack, there is one guard page mapped as inaccessible memory -- if the program accesses it (because it is trying to use more stack than is currently mapped), there's an access violation. The OS catches the fault, maps in another page of stack at the same address as the old guard page, creates a new guard page just beyond the old one, and resumes from the instruction that caused the violation.

If a function has more than one page of local variables, then the first address it accesses might be more than one page beyond the current end of the stack. Hence it would miss the guard page and trigger an access violation that the OS doesn't realise is because more stack is needed. If the total stack required is particularly huge, it could perhaps even reach beyond the guard page, beyond the end of the virtual address space assigned to stack, and into memory that's actually in use for something else.

So, `_chkstk` ensures that there is enough space for the local variables. You can imagine that it does this by touching the memory for the local variables at page-sized intervals, in increasing order, to ensure that it doesn't miss the guard page (so-called "stack probes"). I don't know whether it actually does that, though, possibly it takes a more direct route and instructs the OS to map in a certain amount of stack. Either way, if the total required is greater than the virtual address space available for stack, then the OS can complain about it instead of doing something undefined.

Comment: After reading your answer, I stumbled upon [KB100775: Description of the stack checking for Windows NT-based applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100775). Indeed, "[`_chkstk()`] simply touches memory addresses every 4K from the current stack pointer location to the requested allocation." Thank you for your well-explained answer.

Comment: If you're getting an access violation - check if you have a variable that's too big for the stack. Giant arrays or arrays of arrays are often the culprit.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien Looks like that page is gone. Here's an archive of it. https://archive.is/J01oT

Answer (score 11):

I looked at the code for `__chkstk` and it does do the repeated stack probes at one-page intervals.  So this way, it doesn't need to make any calls to the OS.  The parameter in `rax` is size of data you want to add.  It ensures that the target address (current `rsp` - `rax`) is accessible.  If `rax` > `rsp`, it does this for address 0.  As an interesting shortcut, it first compares the address with `gs:[10h]`, which is the current lowest page that is mapped; if the target address >= this, then it does nothing.

By the way, for 64-bit code at least, it is spelled with two underscores: `__chkstk__`.

Comment: There's only a gs:[10h] stack-bottom value for 64 bit Windows. So the __chkstk-function always touches the pages down the stack.