# stack overflow on stepping into a function

Tags: c++, function, stack-overflow

I'm getting a stack overflow error when I step into a function in debug mode using VS 2015.  Here's the exact message, in case that helps:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0000000140D9F018 in TestProgram.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000213000).

The function I'm entering looks like this:

```
void CGUITaskRequest::DecodeAndDeserializeSettings(const std::string& sEncodedSettingsString)
{
    auto sDecoded = string_functions::base64_decode(sEncodedSettingsString);
    std::stringstream ss(sDecoded);

    if (m_eType == ETaskTypes::FILE && m_eSubtype == ETaskSubtypes::OPEN) {
        auto pSettings = std::make_shared<CModSettingsFileImport>();
        cereal::XMLInputArchive arSettingsObject(ss, pSettings->XML_TAG);   
        pSettings->load(arSettingsObject);
        m_ptrSettings = pSettings;
    }
    else if (m_eType == ETaskTypes::META && m_eSubtype == ETaskSubtypes::STATUS) {
        auto pSettings = std::make_shared<SMetaStatusSettings>();                   
        cereal::XMLInputArchive arSettingsObject(ss, pSettings->XML_TAG); // <- line I comment out to run successfully  
        pSettings->load(arSettingsObject);
        m_ptrSettings = pSettings;
    }
}
```

Here's what's confusing me:

1. I'm *stepping* into the function, so I don't think there can be any recursion going on. When I get the stack overflow error, it's on the opening bracket of the function - none of the lines of the function are even getting called.
2. When I comment out this line in the 'else if' section:
   `cereal::XMLInputArchive arSettingsObject(ss, pSettings->XML_TAG);` 
   then not only does the stack overflow error go away, but the function runs as expected, executing the `if' block successfully (so it successfully creates a 'cereal::XMLInputArchive', loads it from the stringstream, etc).

In both cases (when the function runs, and when it causes a stack overflow), it's getting called with the same input parameter (about 300 chars of base64 encoded xml).

So, somehow, when I compile with all the code uncommented, I cause something to go wrong with the function's execution/memory allocation, but I don't understand what.

Oh yeah, in case this helps, the call stack has this on top when I get the stack overflow error:

> TestProgram.exe!__chkstk()

Other than that, it looks the same as when the function runs successfully (that also leads me to think there's no recursion).

[Edit]

After searching for __chkstk(), I just found/read this SO article:
[What is the purpose of the _chkstk() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400118/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-chkstk-function)

That's making me think that this is not a traditional stack overflow error, where I'm asking for too much memory, rather that something in the function is trying to reference an illegal place in memory, which is causing VS to report a stack overflow.  But, I'm still not sure why/how that could happen if the function isn't even executing, since that block won't run.

Thanks in advance for any insight as to what could cause this type of behavior.

I have a bad feeling that I'm missing something fundamental about function calling.

Comment: It's possible that the stack overflow occurs while pushing parameters for the function onto the stack, but in this case, all that is being passed is a reference (pointer).

Comment: How tall is the call stack when you encounter the crash?

Comment: What's `sizeof(cereal::XMLInputArchive)`? If I recall correctly, `__chkstk` may fail if the function has more than 4K worth of local variables.

Comment: @Axalo - the call stack has 8 items in it - this function is the 8th, __chkstk is the 9th. Igor Tandetnik - sizeof(cereal::XMLInputArchive) yields 66088 -

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik - sizeof(cereal::XMLInputArchive) yields "66088", which I guess is bytes.  Given that my function runs OK with one, I guess my max stack size must be > 4k, but < 2 x 66088.

Comment: Maybe it was 64K, not 4K, that caused problems. Anyway, you may want to avoid placing such a large object on the stack. I would recommend allocating it on the heap instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `_chkstk()` [throws a stack overflow when you have exceeded the  declared maximum stack size declared in an .exe build](https://archive.is/J01oT). Your solution then? [Increase it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations). Though also consider removing the bit of redundancy in your code:

First, consider that upon entering the function, we need to ensure that there is enough space for all local variables of your function on the stack. Let's look at what those are:

```
void CGUITaskRequest::DecodeAndDeserializeSettings(const std::string& sEncodedSettingsString)
{
  /* two variables here */
  auto sDecoded = string_functions::base64_decode(sEncodedSettingsString);
  std::stringstream ss(sDecoded);

  if (m_eType == ETaskTypes::FILE && m_eSubtype == ETaskSubtypes::OPEN) {
    /* two more variables here */
    auto pSettings = std::make_shared<CModSettingsFileImport>();
    cereal::XMLInputArchive arSettingsObject(ss, pSettings->XML_TAG);   
    pSettings->load(arSettingsObject);
    m_ptrSettings = pSettings;
  }
  else if (m_eType == ETaskTypes::META && m_eSubtype == ETaskSubtypes::STATUS) {
    /* and a final pair */
    auto pSettings = std::make_shared<SMetaStatusSettings>();                   
    cereal::XMLInputArchive arSettingsObject(ss, pSettings->XML_TAG); // <- line I comment out to run successfully  
    pSettings->load(arSettingsObject);
    m_ptrSettings = pSettings;
  }
}
```

Now consider that you find the `_chkstk()` variable on the call stack to begin with. This implies that this function [allocates a lot of memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/DevNotes/-win32-chkstk)! That commenting out a single declaration resolves the problem points to the greedy memory culprit. But wait, you have two of these, and that you can get away with one implies that consolidating your duplicated declaration might pay dividends:

```
void CGUITaskRequest::DecodeAndDeserializeSettings(const std::string& sEncodedSettingsString)
{
  auto sDecoded = string_functions::base64_decode(sEncodedSettingsString);
  std::stringstream ss(sDecoded);
  /* single declaration*/
  cereal::XMLInputArchive arSettingsObject;
  if (m_eType == ETaskTypes::FILE && m_eSubtype == ETaskSubtypes::OPEN) {
    auto pSettings = std::make_shared<CModSettingsFileImport>();
    arSettingsObject = cereal::XMLInputArchive(ss, pSettings->XML_TAG);   
    pSettings->load(arSettingsObject);
    m_ptrSettings = pSettings;
  }
  else if (m_eType == ETaskTypes::META && m_eSubtype == ETaskSubtypes::STATUS) {
    auto pSettings = std::make_shared<SMetaStatusSettings>();                   
    arSettingsObject = cereal::XMLInputArchive(ss, pSettings->XML_TAG); // <- line I comment out to run successfully  
    pSettings->load(arSettingsObject);
    m_ptrSettings = pSettings;
  }
}
```

Although this changes the scope on `arSettingsObject`, it isn't a problem because the function terminates after the if/else statement and all return paths from where it is declared require it.

Comment: thanks very much! I used your solution - except that cereal::XMLInputArchive doesn't have a default constructor. So I used a std::unique_ptr to one instead, then created the pointer when necessary. Based on the comment from Igor Tandetnik, I did the 'sizeof' and this variable must be the culprit.  Thanks again!

Comment: I realized after I posted my last comment that my solution not only solved the problem as @OrderNChaos suggested (by reducing the number of declarations), but it also moves the memory allocation to the heap because I had to use a pointer.  Either way, it solved the problem.